# How to execute an emit (socket.io) at a specific time with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

I have an android application which communicates with the NodeJS server through socket.io.

I need my NodeJS server to send an emit at a specific time like 7 o'clock to all clients.

Example:

`socket.emit ('example', 'data', 'hour to emit');`

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it once at a static time you know, then just use `setTimeout` and calculate the difference between the server's current time and the emit time and pass it to `setTimeout` call.

If you want to do it more than once at static times you know, you can store these times in an array an then use `setInterval` with an interval of 1 minute to check if it's time to execute an emit.

The implementation totally depends on your needs. Maybe you need to store execution times in a database and then make a REST api to check for them and configure a cronjob to call this api each minute.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and apparently setTimeout or setInterval are resource intensive. Finally, I opted for CRON at the desired time which makes an HTTP call in GET. Thank's!